# RISC code loop termination

Tags: assembly, instruction-set

This is a RISC code I came across in a book. The code is to multiply 10 with 5.

```
Mov ax,0
Mov bx,10
Mov cx,5
begin : Add ax,bx
        loop begin
```

It is given that total number of cycles taken by this code is 13 cycles. I don't understand how `begin-loop begin` loop gets terminated. We are not setting any condition for that. Can anyone please explain how is it interpreted.

Comment: _"This is a RISC code I came across"_ Are you sure? It looks a lot like x86 assembly. Refer to Volume 2 of the [Intel Software Developer Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) for info on how `loop` works.

Comment: basically a duplicate of [How exactly does the x86 LOOP instruction work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46881279), except for not realizing the ISA.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the idea is that the `loop` instruction will decrement `cx` and only return to `begin` if `cx` is non-zero.  It looks like this supposed RISC was modelled on x86, which is pretty funny because x86 is not only CISC, but aggressively so.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned before, the code looks like it's x86 assembler rather than a RISC instruction set. In x86 the `loop` instruction decrements `CX` and branches if the value is not zero. If you're familiar with C it would look some like this:

```
int ax = 0;
int bx = 10;
int cx = 5;

do
{
  ax += bx;
}while (--cx !=0);
```