# LOOP is done only one time when single stepping in Turbo Debugger

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-16

The code must output 'ccb',but output only 'c', `LOOP` is done only one time, i have calibrated in TD, but why `LOOP` is done only one time?

I THINK THAT I MUST TO DECREMENT STRING_LENGTH, SO I WROTE

```
DEC STRING_LENGTH
```

BUT IT NOT WORK, SO I WROTE LIKE THAT

```
MOV SP,STRING_LENGTH
DEC SP
MOV STRING_LENGTH,SP
```

I KNOW WHAT ARE YOU THINKING RIGHT NOW, THAT IS SO INCORRECT, YOU ARE RIGHT)))

I CAN USE C++, BUT I WANT TO DO IT ONLY IN ASSEMBLY,

```
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 200H
.DATA
STRING DB 'cScbd$'
STRING_LENGTH EQU $-STRING
STRING1 DB STRING_LENGTH DUP (?) , '$'
.CODE
MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX
XOR SI,SI
XOR DI,DI

MOV CX,STRING_LENGTH

S:

MOV BL,STRING[DI]
AND STRING[DI],01111100B
CMP STRING[DI],01100000B
JNE L1
MOV AL,BL
MOV STRING1[SI],AL
ADD SI,2
L1:

ADD DI,2

LOOP S

MOV DL,STRING1
MOV AH,9
INT 21H
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
END
```

Comment: More likely your loop doesn't do what you think it does.  You aren't clobbering CX inside the loop, so it should run `STRING_LENGTH` times.  Use your debugger to single-step and see what you end up with in memory.  What do you want your loop to do, anyway?  And why are you destroying the original `STRING`?

Comment: I used debuger to single-step and see that 
in line MOV CX,STRING-LENGTH //CX IS 0006 
after LOOP S //CX IS 0000
but why?

Comment: Because you looped 6 times.  [How exactly does the x86 LOOP instruction work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46881279)

Comment: But in debuger dont looped 6 times,looped only 1 time

Comment: Then you're using your debugger wrong.  Are you sure you're hitting the single-step button, rather than set-until-higher-address or something?  Even if the branch target of the `loop` instruction was itself, instead of where `S:` is in the source, that would only decrement `CX` by 1.  It's not possible for one execution of `loop` to change CX from 6 to 0.

Comment: After first looping in CX must be 0005,but in CX after first looping is 0000,why?

Comment: I used F8 in DOSBOX,there is written ''F8-STEP''

Comment: **That's impossible**.  Are you sure you didn't just set a breakpoint after the loop or something?  Post a [mcve] of exactly what you did with your debugger if you want help figuring out what's going on with it.

Comment: I am sure that after loop there is not any breakpoint

Comment: in loop position // ax 4663,bx F463,cx 0006,dx F58A,si 0002,di 0002,bp 0100,sp 0200,ds 4658,es 4644,ss 4659,cs 4654,ip 0028
one step after loop // only changes cx 0000,si 000A,di 000C,ip 002A

Comment: The step *definitely* ran more tha 1 instruction.  All those register changes match with the loop running 6 times; your debugger just isn't showing it.  You're running TurboDebugger inside DOSBOX, right?  So you're not using [DOSBOX's built-in debugger](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=3944).  I haven't used TD so IDK why it's not stopping at each instruction.  Google on that, maybe you'll find something.

Comment: It means that loop work 6 times,but why outputs only 'c'  in place 'ccb'?

Comment: maybe outputs algorithm is wrong?

Comment: `MOV DL,STRING1` is obviously wrong.  That's a load from memory of one byte, but `int 21h/ah=9` takes a pointer in DX.  http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09.  It's probably just random chance that it prints anything at all.  Use your debugger to examine memory and see what DX points to, and also check that your loop filtered into STRING1 correctly.

Comment: In Turbo Debugger (TD.EXE) the "F8 step" will "execute" the `loop` instruction completely (`cx` many times, or more, if the code will modify `cx` meanwhile). Use the "F7 trace" option to go from cx=6 to cx=5. (upvoted because you are trying to debug, keep communicating after posting question, and the TD UI is somewhat tricky in this particular case, but otherwise you have still a lot of work ahead of you).

Comment: Inside the loop when it writes to string1, it writes one byte, but increments si by 2.

Comment: The loop iterates 6 times and increments di by 2 each time, so it goes way past the end of the input string, overwriting as it goes.

Answer (score 5):

In Turbo Debugger (TD.EXE) the <kbd>F8</kbd> "F8 step" will execute the `loop` completely, until the `cx` becomes zero (you can even create infinite loop by updating `cx` back to some value, preventing it from reaching the 1 -> 0 step).

To get "single-step" out of the `loop` instruction, use the <kbd>F7</kbd> "F7 trace" - that will cause the `cx` to go from 6 to 5, and the code pointer will follow the jump back on the start of the loop.

---

About some other issues of your code:

```
MOV SP,STRING_LENGTH
DEC SP
MOV STRING_LENGTH,SP
```

`sp` is not general purpose register, don't use it for calculation like this. Whenever some instruction does use stack implicitly (`push, pop, call, ret, ...`), the values are being written and read in memory area addressed by the `ss:sp` register pair, so by manipulating the `sp` value you are modifying the current "stack".

Also in 16 bit x86 real mode all the interrupts (keyboard, timer, ...), when they occur, the current state of flag register and code address is stored into stack, before giving the control to the interrupt handler code, which usually will push additional values to the stack, so whatever is in memory on addresses below current `ss:sp` is not safe in 16 bit x86 real mode, and the memory content keeps "randomly" changing there by all the interrupts being executed meanwhile (the TD.EXE itself does use part of this stack memory after every single step).

For arithmetic use other registers, not `sp`. Once you will know enough about "stack", you will understand what kind of `sp` manipulation is common and why (like `sub sp,40` at beginning of function which needs additional "local" memory space), and how to restore stack back into expected state.

---

One more thing about that:

```
MOV SP,STRING_LENGTH
DEC SP
MOV STRING_LENGTH,SP
```

The `STRING_LENGTH` is defined by `EQU`, which makes it compile time constant, and only compile time. It's not "variable" (memory allocation), contrary to the things like `someLabel dw 1345`, which cause the assembler to emit two bytes with values `0100_0001B, 0000_0101B` (when read as 16 bit word in little-endian way, that's value 1345 encoded), and the first byte address has symbolic name `someLabel`, which can be used in further instructions, like `dec word ptr [someLabel]` to decrement that value in memory from 1345 to 1344 during runtime.

But `EQU` is different, it assigns the symbol `STRING_LENGTH` final value, like 14.

So your code can be read as:

```
mov sp,14   ; makes almost sense, (practically destroys stack setup)
dec sp      ; still valid
mov 14,sp   ; doesn't make any sense, constant can't be destination for MOV
```