# Assembly 8086, LOOP instruction doesn't stop

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16

The following code is for assembly 8086, I'm looping using `LOOP` instruction.

The loop continues forever after `CL` becomes zero and it changes the `CX` value to FFFFh.
But if I change the value of `CL` to maximum 06h, the loop stops properly.
Moreover, if I remove first `LOOP AGAIN` it will work fine.

```
DATA DB 01001100b

MOV AL, DATA
MOV CL, 08h
SUB BL, BL
SUB DL, DL

AGAIN:
ROL AL, 1  
JC SKIP
INC BL
LOOP AGAIN

SKIP: 
INC DL
LOOP AGAIN
```

I expect it to stop when `CL` becomes zero. Any idea why it isn't behaving as expected?

**UPDATE 1**
I have noticed when `CL` (or `CX` when using 16 bit) reaches 1 and last bit is 0, then the first `LOOP AGAIN` won't jump up and operation continues to the *SKIP* part. If I change the last bit of *DATA* to 1 it will make the `JC SKIP` and everything works just fine.

Comment: The loop counter is `cx`, not `cl`.  If you set `cl` to a value, make sure `ch` is zero before doing so.

Comment: after first `loop` the `cx` is zero. If the second `loop` is then reached, it does decrement `cx` (i.e. 0 -> 0xFFFF) so the second loop will run 65536 times before `cx` will reach zero again, then it will finish. Can't see why it would "not stop", it will. (and use full 16 bit `cx` in your code to set up counter, `cl` is just low 8 bits of it, so you don't know what is in upper 8 bits (`ch`))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly does the x86 LOOP instruction work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46881622), but I think there's a more specific duplicate about nested `loop` instructions somewhere.  (`loop` can only fall through when it leaves CX=0, meaning the next `loop` can't fall through, so it's an infinite loop.)

Comment: oh, the second loop is going all the way up ahead of first loop, I forgot to check, so yes, this will never stop, that's correct description of the current state... So you want probably in the end some jump after the first loop, if I now understand what you are trying to do.. (counting zeroes and ones separately), something like `jmp AfterSecondLoop` ... but actually simply calculate only one counter, the other is 8-counter, so you can calculate it after loop does finish with one subtract. Your "update" is correct. So do you understand why it works like this?

Comment: Oh, yes this looks like unintentionally nested loops because of accidental fall-through after tail duplication.  I don't see the point, though, just count ones in the loop.  You can get the count of zeros by doing `8 - bl` outside the loop with a `mov dl, 8` / `sub dl, bl`.

Comment: @PeterCorde, @Ped7g Yes I can just do the subtract, but I don't understand this codes' behavior, it's not nested loop, just one loop but with two jumps using `CX`, its more like a compound statement `if(CX==0){ INC BL} else{INC DL}`.
my point is why if the first condition met, `LOOP` instruction won't do the jump while subtracting `CX` by 1?

Comment: Look at what happens if the first `LOOP AGAIN` is not-taken.  It falls through into what's supposed to be the else block, which *also* contains a `loop again` which will then decrement CX to `0xFFFF` and jump to the top.  You need an extra `jmp` out of the loop in case the `loop` after INC BL falls through.  Single-step it with a debugger and watch it happen.  And BTW, did you mean `if(CF==0) { INC BL } else { INC DL }`?  Your `loop` is supposed to be a loop around that, with tail duplication.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your explanation, I got it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Easy answer

```
    MOV  AL, 01001100b
    MOV  CX, 0008h
    SUB  BL, BL
    SUB  DL, DL
AGAIN:
    ROL  AL, 1  
    JC   SKIP
    INC  BL
    LOOP AGAIN    ; The 1st
    JMP  ENDOFLOOP
SKIP:
    INC  DL
    LOOP AGAIN    ; The 2nd
ENDOFLOOP:
```

- The `LOOP` instruction on 8086 always uses the `CX` register (all of it).
- Your code missed an unconditional jump below the 1st `LOOP AGAIN` in case the loop should terminate there. This is to avoid falling through in the *SKIP* part of the program.

### How it fails

> ```
>     MOV AL, 01001100b
>     MOV CL, 08h
>     SUB BL, BL
>     SUB DL, DL
> AGAIN:
>     ROL AL, 1  
>     JC SKIP
>     INC BL
>     LOOP AGAIN    ; The 1st
> SKIP: 
>     INC DL
>     LOOP AGAIN    ; The 2nd
> ```

This is what the code does (assuming `CH=0`):

```
         ROL AL, 1                         LOOP
AL=01001100b   AL=10011000b   CF=0  BL=1   CX=7  The 1st jumps back
AL=10011000b   AL=00110001b   CF=1  DL=1   CX=6  The 2nd jumps back
AL=00110001b   AL=01100010b   CF=0  BL=2   CX=5  The 1st jumps back
AL=01100010b   AL=11000100b   CF=0  BL=3   CX=4  The 1st jumps back
AL=11000100b   AL=10001001b   CF=1  DL=2   CX=3  The 2nd jumps back
AL=10001001b   AL=00010011b   CF=1  DL=3   CX=2  The 2nd jumps back
AL=00010011b   AL=00100110b   CF=0  BL=4   CX=1  The 1st jumps back
AL=00100110b   AL=01001100b   CF=0  BL=5   CX=0  The 1st FALLS THROUGH!!!
```

At this point because `CX` became 0 the 1st `LOOP AGAIN` no longer jumps back. 
The code falls through and falsely increments the `DL` register. The 2nd `LOOP AGAIN` also pinches off 1 from `CX` producing `CX=65535`.
So the program happily continues for a very long time **but it does not become an infinite loop**. Because the loop counter is no longer a multiple of 8 (the number of bits in `AL`), at some point it will be the 2nd `LOOP AGAIN` that will make `CX=0` at which point the program will finally stop.

### Why it seems to work with modifications

> but if I change the value of CL to maximum 06h, the loop stops properly

This is what the code does with `CX=6`:

```
         ROL AL, 1                         LOOP
AL=01001100b   AL=10011000b   CF=0  BL=1   CX=5  The 1st jumps back
AL=10011000b   AL=00110001b   CF=1  DL=1   CX=4  The 2nd jumps back
AL=00110001b   AL=01100010b   CF=0  BL=2   CX=3  The 1st jumps back
AL=01100010b   AL=11000100b   CF=0  BL=3   CX=2  The 1st jumps back
AL=11000100b   AL=10001001b   CF=1  DL=2   CX=1  The 2nd jumps back
AL=10001001b   AL=00010011b   CF=1  DL=3   CX=0  The 2nd FALLS THROUGH!!!
```

Because it's the 2nd `LOOP AGAIN` that falls through, there's no problem since we're at the bottom of the program.

> If I change the last bit of DATA to 1 it will make the JC SKIP and everything works just fine

This is what the code does with `AL=01001101b`:

```
         ROL AL, 1                         LOOP
AL=01001101b   AL=10011010b   CF=0  BL=1   CX=7  The 1st jumps back
AL=10011010b   AL=00110101b   CF=1  DL=1   CX=6  The 2nd jumps back
AL=00110101b   AL=01101010b   CF=0  BL=2   CX=5  The 1st jumps back
AL=01101010b   AL=11010100b   CF=0  BL=3   CX=4  The 1st jumps back
AL=11010100b   AL=10101001b   CF=1  DL=2   CX=3  The 2nd jumps back
AL=10101001b   AL=01010011b   CF=1  DL=3   CX=2  The 2nd jumps back
AL=01010011b   AL=10100110b   CF=0  BL=4   CX=1  The 1st jumps back
AL=10100110b   AL=01001101b   CF=1  DL=4   CX=0  The 2nd FALLS THROUGH!!!
```

Because it's the 2nd `LOOP AGAIN` that falls through, there's no problem since we're at the bottom of the program.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation (and re-formatting the question ;) ), I appreciate it.