# I want to add random integers from a range of j to k into two different arrays. Why are they being added to both arrays with just the first loop?

Tags: loops, assembly

This problem is with assembly code. I have watch on both arrays and am debugging it and I see that with just the first loop the same values are being added to both arrays. Why is this? How can I fix it so that one array is has elements added to it for the first loop then for the second loop random elements are added to the second array? Another problem I found is that the loop goes on forever even though I started ecx at 5 and am decrementing it each time. Why is this?

Here is my code.

```
.data
    arr dword 5 DUP(?)
    arr2 dword 5 DUP(?)
    j dword ? ; upper
    k dword ? ; lower
    n dword 5
.code
main PROC
    ; test 1 k = 20 and j = 500
    mov k, 500
    mov j, 20
    mov ecx, n
    mov esi, offset arr
L1: 
    call BetterRandomRange

    mov [esi], eax
    add esi, type arr
    dec ecx
    loop L1

    ; test 2 k = 200 and j = -300 
    mov k, -300
    mov j, 200
    mov ecx, n
    mov esi, offset arr2
L2: 
    call BetterRandomRange
    mov [esi], eax
    add esi, type arr
    dec ecx
    loop L2


    INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP

BetterRandomRange PROC
    mov eax, k
    mov ebx, j
    sub eax, ebx
    inc eax
    call Randomize
    call RandomRange 
    call WriteInt
    call Crlf
    add eax, ebx

    ret
BetterRandomRange ENDP




end main
```

Comment: `loop` already decrements `ecx` you don't need the `dec ecx`.

Comment: And `n` is odd, so `dec ecx` when ecx=1 will leave `ecx=0` when `loop` runs, and it's like the bottom of a `do{}while(--ecx)`, so it doesn't exit the loop.  [How exactly does the x86 LOOP instruction work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46881622) goes into the details.  So you'll crash at some point when your pointer increment gets out of range, before you can finish (2^32) / 2 iterations to get back to `1` *after* `dec`.  TL:DR: remove the `dec ecx`, or better don't use `loop` because it's slow.